# How i can count the instance of ckeditor exist on webpage in javascript?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

How i can count the instance of ckeditor exist on webpage in javascript ? can anyone show me sample code for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getNumberOfInstances(){
    var x = 0; // x is the number of instances
    for(var instances in CKEDITOR.instances){
        x ++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: It's worth giving a link to the api. http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html

Answer (score -2):

Just do it manually,There may be an easy way to do it . It is simple idea.

try it

for example

```
var total_ck = new array();

var oEditor1 = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('field1');//instance 1

total_ck.push("field1"); 

var oEditor2 = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('field2');//instance 2
total_ck.push("field2");

var oEditor3 = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('field3');//instance 3
total_ck.push("field3");

var numberof_fck = total_ck.length;

alert(numberof_fck );
```

Comment: i write the code who increase count manually and tell me how much instance currently created. because you help me. thanks

Comment: That code is for the old FCKeditor, not for CKEditor as it has been requested, and only works if you know the existing fields in advance.